# Why does "bash -x" break this script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script which measures how long some command executes.

It needs the "real" `time` command, meaning, a binary for example in `/usr/bin/time` (as the bash-built-in doesn't have the `-f`flag).

Below, a simplified script which can be debugged:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESEC=$(echo blah | ( /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah >/dev/null ) 2>&1 | awk -F. '{print $1}')

echo ABC--$TIMESEC--DEF

if [ "$TIMESEC" -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo "we are here!"
fi
```

Save as "test.sh" and execute:

```
$ bash test.sh
ABC--0--DEF
we are here!
```

So it worked.

Now, let's try to debug this by adding "-x" to bash command line:

```
$ bash -x test.sh
++ echo blah
++ awk -F. '{print $1}'
+ TIMESEC='++ /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah
0'
+ echo ABC--++ /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah 0--DEF
ABC--++ /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah 0--DEF
+ '[' '++ /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah
0' -eq 0 ']'
test.sh: line 10: [: ++ /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah
0: integer expression expected
```

Why does this script break when we're using "-x", and works fine without it?

Comment: Heh. It looks like with `-x` on, that the `$()` construct is getting the `-x` output included as part of its resulting value. Don't know if that is "expected" behavior or a bug though...  Or maybe it is the subshell `()` inside that is actually giving the `-x` output.

Comment: Aside: Setting `BASH_XTRACEFD` lets you redirect `set -x` output to somewhere it's less trouble.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is this line:

```
TIMESEC=$(echo blah | ( /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah >/dev/null ) 2>&1 | awk -F. '{print $1}')
```

where you are redirecting the standard error to match the standard output.  bash is writing its trace-messages to the standard error, and is (for instance) using its built-in `echo` along with other shell constructs all in the bash process.

If you change it to something like

```
TIMESEC=$(echo blah | sh -c "( /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah >/dev/null )" 2>&1 | awk -F. '{print $1}')
```

it will work around that problem, and perhaps be an acceptable compromise between tracing and working:

```
++ awk -F. '{print $1}'
++ sh -c '( /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah >/dev/null )'
++ echo blah
+ TIMESEC=0                 
+ echo ABC--0--DEF
ABC--0--DEF
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'we are here!'
we are here!
```

Answer (score 7):

you can also just drop the subshell. apparently it is the nested shells which wind up upsetting one another:

```
TIMESEC=$(
    echo blah |
    /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah 2>&1 >/dev/null |
    awk -F. '{print $1}'
)
```

---

If you do:

---

```
...| ( subshell ) 2>pipe | ...
```

---

... you wind up with the subshell launched to handle that section of the pipeline *hosting* the subshell within. Because the shell without redirects even the debug output of the subshell within *(as it would also do for any other kind of `{` compound command`; } >redirect` you might choose to use)*   to its section of the pipeline you wind up mixing streams. It has to do with the order of redirection.

Instead, if you simply first redirect *only* the error output of the commands you're attempting gauge, and let the host shell's output make it to stderr, you don't wind up with the same problem.

and so...

---

```
... | command 2>pipe 1>/dev/null | ...
```

---

...the host shell is free to continue writing its stderr where it pleases while only redirecting the output of the commands which it calls into the pipe.

---

```
bash -x time.sh
+++ echo blah
+++ /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah
+++ awk -F. '{print $1}'
++ TIMESEC=0
++ echo ABC--0--DEF
ABC--0--DEF
++ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
++ echo 'we are here!'
we are here!
```

---

For that matter...

---

```
TIMESEC=$(
    echo blah |
    /usr/bin/time -f %e grep blah 2>&1 >/dev/null
)
printf %s\\n "ABC--${TIMESEC%%.*}--DEF"
if [ "${TIMESEC%%.*}" -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo "we are here!"
fi
```